# R behaving as though there are NAs in my data

Tags: r

I am trying to log transform my data and then test to see if it is normal.

```
> edata_log = mutate(edata, LogCoalPC=log(CoalPerCapita))
> shapiro.test(edata_log$LogCoalPC)
Shapiro-Wilk normality test
data:  edata_log$LogCoalPC
W = NaN, p-value = NA
```

But there are no null values in my data:

```
> df_log[is.na(df_log$A),]
[1] LogColumnA ColumnB
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

So I am not sure what is causing this error.

The same thing happens when I try to use qqplot:

```
> qqplot(edata_log$Region~edata_log$LogCoalPC)
Error in sort(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
```

Here is some of the data:

```
> head(edata$LogCoalPC)

LogCoalPC
-2.130651
-3.699430
-1.890638
-2.987920
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you give a reproducible example. Perhaps look at `str(edata)` A common cause of bewildering errors is when a column that you think is numeric is actually character or factor. How that would cause the errors you see I don't quite know, but making sure that the columns are as you think they are is a good initial step in debugging.

Comment: Do you have any zeros in your data? These will become `NaN` after you take their log, so if you check for missing values before taking the log you might miss them.

Comment: Taking the log of a negative value is also not defined thus could cause the error.

Comment: @Marius There was a zero in my data! Thank you, sorry for asking such a silly question.